# How to escape spaces etc in passed variable, for system call to cp in awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, quoting

This problem has enough layers of complexity to make simple escaping characters difficult for me. I have a bash script which, for a large part, has an embedded awk script that reads a file delimited by semicolons. In this text file, one of the fields is a directory path to some JPEGs. I'd like to copy the JPEGs somewhere else, but the original directory path has spaces in it (and could potentially have other strings that could do damage). I can't refer to the directory in question with single quotes because this stops the awk interpreter, and double quotes turns it into a literal string in awk.

I'm using gawk 4.1.1. Here's some awk code of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
imageDirectory = $1;
cpJpegVariable="cp -r " imageDirectory " assets";
#screws up if imageDirectory has spaces and other naughty characters
system(cpJpegVariable);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk '...
    cpJpegVariable="cp -r '\''" imageDirectory "'\'' assets";
    ...'
```

(note that `'` doesn't need escaping for `awk`, but you need `'\''` for the shell). So when `awk` expands variable `cpJpegVariable`, it looks like:

```
cp -r 'file_contain space' assets
```

With that, you can avoid problem with all special characters, except `'` itself. If `imageDirectory` may contain single quote characters, you can escape them with `gsub()`. Example:

```
awk '{gsub("'\''","'\''\"'\''\"",imageDirectory)}1'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, and embarassingly obivous in hindsight. Thanks very much.

Comment: Note that while it fixes the problem with space, tab, ;, |, & and many other characters, it does not fix it for filenames that contain backtick, backslash, `$` or `"` characters (or whose name starts with `-`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: If change `\"` to `\'`, problem maybe fixed?

Comment: To `'` you mean? Then, the only problematic character becomes `'` itself (which you can escape with a `gsub` command).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks for suggestion, fixed!

Comment: You can't escape `'` with backslash (inside single quotes)

Comment: I mean that `echo 'foo\'bar'` is wrong.

Comment: Oh, my bad! Thinking it in double quotes. Do you think change it to `'foo'"'"'bar'` works?

Comment: For reference, under gawk 4.1.1 `cpJpegVariable="cp -r \'" imageDirectory "\' assets";` does not work. Escaping single quotes doesn't seem to work in this version of gawk, and it's very frustrating. This was the original source of my confusion for this question.

Comment: Thanks @Gnouc, your last edit with escaped single quotes and gsub was really useful. I just tested the code and it works nicely.

Comment: Not, me. It's @StéphaneChazelas, we both thanks him.

Comment: fwiw, you could have defined a `sq` ("single-quote") variable to hold a single quote, using `\047` (... if you use the C locale... You may need to cast awk with LC_ALL=C or some other compatible locale) for ex: `BEGIN{ sq="\047" } ;   { cmd="printf " sq "%\\n" sq " " sq $0 qs ; system(cmd); close(cmd) }'`  # should print the lines you give as input ... Your line then becomes: `cpJpegVariable="cp -r " sq imageDirectory sq " assets";`  which i find quite readable

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing an Awk variable to *system*, you need to shell quote it:

```
function quote(str,   d, m, x, y, z) {
  d = "\47"; m = split(str, x, d)
  for (y in x) z = z d x[y] d (y < m ? "\\" d : "")
  return z
}
```

Example:

```
system(sprintf("cp -r %s assets", quote($1)))
```

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/stdlib/blob/3216068/stdlib.awk#L26-L32)

Answer (score -1):

Executing external commands is meant for the shell, not for awk:

```
while read image_dir __; do
    cp -r "$image_dir" assets
done < file
```

Comment: It is sometimes necessary or useful to execute a system command based on information that was read by awk. This is why system() exists.

Comment: `system()` is not consistent with all types of input. It's awfully difficult to sanitize it.